# 2 consecutive redirection impact for search engines

Tags: wordpress, prestashop, search-engine, redirect

I have an e-shop part (Prestashop) and a blog part (Wordpress).
I did a migration to new websites (Prestashop + Wordpress as well).
One difference is in the old version some pages were located on the e-shop and now, they have to be placed on the blog part.

The goal is to avoid to get 404 errors for all old links and keep the ranking on search engines.

So, I have all dead URL links on Google like this :

```
eshop.myexample.com/blog/cars/{car_id}
```

I need to do the first redirection in `eshop.myexample.com` (Prestashop .htaccess ) to force every link with this "regex" to redirect to the WordPress part which is :

```
myexample.com/blog/cars/{car_id}
```

Then, as `/blog/cars/{car_id}` does not match with the new page, I have to use a tool (plugin) to redirect inside the wp site each page like this :

```
myexample.com/blog/cars/{car_id} => myexample.com/cars/{post_id}
```

So we have 2 consecutive redirections. The explanation is a little difficult but the question is easy :

In case of 2 consecutive redirections, what is the ranking Google behavior?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the question has been raised here : https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5114/seo-will-multiple-redirects-301-permalink-plugin-affect-ranking

I think two 301 successvely won't really affect as soon as the page was not really referenced before on that URL.